# comparator problem

Tags: amplifier, integrated-circuit, comparator

where is the mistake in my circuit?
i attempted to create simple continuity tester, image really explains it pretty much.

IC - ne5532p

[image: schematic]

PS: i know reference voltages on two op amp (+) terminals are 1/11* vcc and 1/101*vcc instead of 1/10*vcc and 1/100*vcc, but i dont care.

Comment: If I interpret the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/product/NE5532/datasheet/abstract#SLOS0758745) correctly, the opamp doesn't support rail-to-rail inputs. Your input voltages are too close to the power supply rail.

Comment: Apart from the above, it wouldn't be a bad idea to explain in your question how you think the circuit works and what it actually does.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you swap the inputs on each opamp?

Comment: okay i want my circuit to take a reference voltage (marked on image) and compare it to two values, made by voltage divider. In a nutshell i want first led to light at <5ohm resistance between probes and <50ohm resistance should light second light up

Comment: In addition, per the data sheet, the minimum recommended supplies are +5 -5.

Comment: does that mean that +5 and GND (0v) wont work properly and i cant even use a 9volt battery to fix the issue? sounds useless then .....

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration all of the previous comments two potential choices to get this design working are:

1) If you must use these op-amp parts then increase the supplies to +5v/-5v or more.

2) If you must use the existing 6v supply then find a different op-amp pair rated for low voltage/single supply, rail to rail input.

Comment: would 9Volt battery be sufficient to solve supply voltage problem with this IC? Can i use it with only single supply even?

Comment: Using a single 9v battery might work, but again this would not be guaranteed by the data sheet.  If you were to use two 9v batteries that would get you well into the data sheet requirements.  (If you use that method be sure to use a double pole switch for the + and - supply ends.  Also watch out for any excessive currents and any negative voltages getting where they shouldn't be.)